# How to display certain links in a menu only if a precondition is met?

Tags: 8

I've added a checkbox to menu creation so that certain items in the menu will be displayed only if that checkbox is ticked (`For test user`).

[image]

That's the theory anyway.

How can I determine if that checkbox is ticked when displaying the menu on a page?
I assume some hook is involved here, but I can't quite figure out which one.

Any nudging in the right direction is more than welcome.

Comment: A nudge in the right direction would be to hook into the access of the target of the menu link. This controls the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to store value of 'For Test User' checkbox as variable OR as separate column in menu_links table.

like variable_set(url, checkbox_value);

By using hook_menu_alter you can check the variable is set for that url. and if its not set you can set $items['url']['access callback'] = FALSE, By setting this menu will not be visible.

Let me know if anything different required.